# IF function to identify first character of cell

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use the IF function in Excel so that if the first character of a cell is `9`, then the value shown should be the eight rightmost characters of that cell, otherwise the value shown should be the four rightmost characters. This formula however does not work:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)=9,RIGHT(A2,8),RIGHT(A2,4))
```

It keeps returning the rightmost four numbers even though the number in cell A2 starts with `9`.

Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT`returns text, so the comparison needs to also be against a string:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="9",RIGHT(A2,8),RIGHT(A2,4))
```

or you need to convert the result of `LEFT` to a number again:

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A2,1))=9,RIGHT(A2,8),RIGHT(A2,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

try =IF(INT(LEFT(A2,1))=9,RIGHT(A2,8),RIGHT(A2,4))

Comment: I just ran it, it works. =INT(LEFT(A2,1)) should return 9, and =INT(LEFT(A2,1))=9 should return TRUE

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version if the condition is used to set the number of characters:

```
=RIGHT(A2,4+4*(LEFT(A2)="9"))
```